# Command line : arguments, options and paramaters

Tags: maven, command-line, command-line-interface

I'm trying to have a better understanding about how command line work

I'm a bit confused when it comes to arguments, options and subcommand

Let's imagine with maven (a java build tool) :

```
mvn clean install
```

mvn is the command line program. But what are 'clean' and 'install' ? Are they arguments or subcommands ?

Let's imagine another example :

```
prog -a arg
```

prog is the command line program. -a is an option and arg an argument. How do you know if arg is the arguments belonging to the 'prog' or an argument belonging to the option '-a' ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Are they arguments or subcommands

It depends. If the program has a hierarchy in its arguments, they would be sub-commands, like here:

```
docker image ls
```

(The `docker` program has a command/command group `image` and a sub-command `ls`.)

If the program takes arguments in order to express a serial execution, they would be just arguments, like here:

```
mvn clean install
```

(The `mvn` program will first execute the `clean` lifecycle, then execute up to the `install` phase in the `default` lifecycle, see [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html).)

I see that often arguments have a meaningful order, such as with Maven, while options more-commonly can be placed anywhere. For Maven, there's arguments like `-D...`, `-e`, `-U` (to mention a few common ones). They could go anywhere:

```
mvn -e clean -DskipTests install -Dcheckstyle.skip=true ... et cetera
```

With other programs the order of options may matter, like [`find` has "tests"](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find). They look like options (in the sense that they have `-option`-notation), although one could argue they are arguments. In other words, *it depends*.

> `prog -a arg`
>   How do you know if arg is the arguments belonging to the 'prog' or an argument belonging to the option '-a'

Again, *it depends* on the definition of the `a` option. If it doesn't take an argument, it's sometimes called a *flag*. If it *does* take an argument, that is part of the specification of the option, and the command-line parser of the program can account for that.

Personally, I learned a lot from building command-line tools using [Click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/#documentation). (And by no means an expert.)